# How to apply Grain in FFMPEG like CAPCUT Grain adjustment

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, video

I'm trying to find information about how to apply grain in video using ffmpeg, but unfortunally i couldn't find a viable solution.

I need to apply a grain like Capcut. [Here screenshot](https://prnt.sc/bbongQdfSfTh)

I was reading something about it in ffmpeg documentation page, but i didn't find something related.

[Documentation i was reading](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Color-adjustment)

Can someone guide me what command I could apply with ffmpeg to be able to get something like this? [Here screenshot](https://prnt.sc/bbongQdfSfTh)

I need this command to apply it in Node/Express using Fluent-FFmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

After two days of finding and testing many solutions, I finally found the solution for me.

Here we have the command that I found: [>> Screenshot here <<](https://prnt.sc/Bi9NWO1sVJX5)

Add `denoiser` - `Grain` (like capcut) using `FFMpeg`

```
$ ffmpeg -i beach.mp4 -vf "noise=alls=5" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

You can modify the value of `alls=` as you want.